# Unable To Add Default Header Image

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Tried to add default-image tag in functions.php but it's not working. It's only work when i upload img from wp dashboard but default img is not working

#### `functions.php`

```php
<?php

    add_theme_support('title-tag');

    add_theme_support('custom-header', array(

        'default-image' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.jpg',

    ));

?>
```

#### CSS

```css
#logo{ 
      width: 890px;
      position: relative;
      height: 200px;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<div id="logo" style="background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) no-repeat;">
    <div id="logo_text">
    <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
        <h1><a href="index.html"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a></h1>
        <h2><?php bloginfo('description');?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are working on parent theme or child theme? Can you please check if image path is correct?

Comment: Child theme and the image path is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found that adding default image path in child theme is quite different.

Keep path like this and it will work.

```
add_theme_support('custom-header', array(
    'default-image' => '%2$s/images/logo.jpg',
));
```

In parent theme `%s` should be used while in child theme `%2$s` should be used.

See examples in this page. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_default_headers

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the background-image in css file?

1. Remove the code from functions.php
2. Make the html code as

```html
<div id="logo">
  <div id="logo_text">
    <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
    <h1><a href="index.html"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a></h1>
    <h2><?php bloginfo('description');?></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Add the style

```css
#logo { 
  width: 890px;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background-image:url('../images/logo.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but if i delete this code 
<div id="logo" style="background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) no-repeat;">
then how will i connect it to wp to add header dynamically

Comment: Please refer the link

https://scottbolinger.com/add-a-custom-logo-uploader-to-the-wordpress-theme-customizer/

Add add_action( 'customize_register', 'm1_customize_register' ); in functions.php. No need to add in a seperate file(customizer.php).Then call theme_mod() in the url of <img>